# I want to generate random numbers between 1 - 3 and each generated random number should repeat 5 times. Please help me out

Tags: r

I want to generate random numbers between 1 - 3 and each generated random number should repeat 5 times. Please help me out.

Output Should like this
2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 ....

Comment: What you have so far?

Comment: Something like `rep(sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), each = 5)`? (You might have runs of more than 5 in that case).

Comment: sample(c(1,2,3),size=4800,replace=T)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@AnandaMahto's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750778/i-want-to-generate-random-numbers-between-1-3-and-each-generated-random-number/24751047#comment38399934_24750778), you could sample integers from the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution): `rep(rbinom(n,2,p)+1,each=5)` where `n` is the number of sets of five identical values and `p` is the probability parameter of the sampling distribution. Adding 1 ensures values range from 1 to 3.  E.g.:

```
>set.seed(8);rep(rbinom(9,2,.5)+1,each=5)
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
[39] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Clearly this also does not guarantee that consecutive sets of five values won't be identical; this example produced a run of 20 twos (i.e., four sets of five twos each). Extreme values of `p` (which must be between 0–1) can make such outcomes more likely, in case that's something you'd want to tweak.